# .cumsum() puzzling effect

Tags: python, pandas

Was reviewing the [accepted answer of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890964/cumulative-sum-on-time-series-split-by-consecutive-negative-or-positive-values?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

The section in the demonstration that confuses me is

```
In [37]: (sign != sign.shift()).cumsum()
Out[37]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
Name: values, dtype: int64
```

It *appears* that everytime the (sign != sign.shift()) gives a `True` result,  `cumsum()` returns an incremented number, and keeps returning that number until it encounters another True.

Looking at the [sparse docs for .cumsum](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), I have no idea how/why that behavior is occuring, however useful that it is!

My only guess is cumsum() treats `True` as 1 and `False` as 0.  Doesn't seem like a pythonic thing to do -- sounds like something from C.

Could someone explain why this effect occurs?

Comment: You are right when doing the sum , True :1 and False : 0

Comment: `bool` is subclass `int` in `numpy` -  [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17383140/2901002)

Comment: That's a python behavior, not only numpy. If you type `True+True` in any python version, it returns `2`